# How to Post JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to post a large JSON string containing tweets.  Some of these tweets contain double quotes and lots of special characters.  Do I need to encode the JSON string? My code works if there are no special characters or double quotes in the tweets, otherwise I don't get a response.

```
String jsonString = "{'data': [";

for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
    jsonString +="{'text': '" + tweet.getText() + "'},";
} 
jsonString += "]}";

public void analyseTweets(String jsonString){
        try {
            // Send data
            URL url = new URL("http://twittersentiment.appspot.com/api/bulkClassifyJson");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(jsonString);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error dude!: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code that actually constructs jsonString would probably be more relevant.

Comment: If you don't escape double quotes inside string values ... it's not valid JSON. Furthermore, the way you are doing it using single quotes is not valid JSON. In addition, a trailing comma in an array isn't valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com/ is a nifty tool for making sure your JSON is valid

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Didn't realize how invalid my json was.  Jsonlint helps.  I've decided to just ignore all tweets containing double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an external library such as [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to handle the JSON encoding for you?

From the project description:

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend to use [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to compose JSON you want to POST.
2. If you are composing string from parts, I recommend to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` classes, instead of `+` operators.
3. Use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of `UrlConnection` and call `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");` before making the request. It is required because by default, if you don't set it directly, your request is going to be a `GET` request, not a `POST` one.
4. URLEncode your data before sending it to the server.